# Play .h264 files webplayer

Tags: html, video, h.264

I am trying to play a .h264 file on my website(A file with .h264 suffix, not .mp4!) Is there any way I can do this? The html  tag doesn't seem to support it.

The website is running on a Raspberry pi, and it impossible to convert them automatically to mp4, because it will crash the backend. The videos are generated by a camera mounted on the raspberry pi.

html:

```
 % if loaded_video is not None:
                                <video width="720" height="480" controls>
                                    <source src="/movies/{{loaded_video.name}}" type="video/mp4" />

                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                </video>
```

Even when loading the video url directly, all I see is gibberish.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: ["you can serve your video in both WebM format and MPEG H.264 AAC format"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Comment: I don't think the browser cares about the *extension* so much as it does the MIME type sent from the server.  I think you can also specify the codec to use in the `<video>` tag, so as long as the codec is supported, it should work.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Well from the same thing I linked, I'm pretty sure it's already sending the H.264 codec since an MP4 is just a container for it, but "MP4s encoded with a high profile will not run on lower end hardware, such as low end Firefox OS phones." Direct `.h264` format won't work however, since the same article mentions that it's not a royalty-free format. For that reason, the browser vendors had to explicitly _not_ support the extension.

Comment: @sjagr So It is impossible then?

Comment: Can your Raspberry Pi encode an mp4 with a low-complexity profile? Maybe it would work then.

Comment: I am not sure, it is already under a big load running our teams software. But I can give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the broadway emscripten javascript h264 decoder port to display h264 files in a browser. If you seek for real-time, you'll also need a websocket server/relay and make sure you are sending properly chunked NAL (h264 frames). I wrote a project for this very precise purpose (live stream from rpi cam to a browser using raw h264), see "github h264-live-player"

Answer (score 0):

A web browser will not play a raw .264 file. It must be put into a container such as mp4. If it is live video, many moderns browsers can use media source extensions to play a fragmented mp4 (m4s)

> it impossible to convert them automatically to mp4, because it will
>   crash the backend.

Then this is a bug. Fix the crash.

> @sjagr

Yes, h.264 is not royalty free, but wrapping it an an mp4 does not remove that restriction. *.264 is just h.264 NAULs saved in annexB format. It is part of the h.264 specification.

Comment: It will crash the backend because of the low computing power in the raspberry. Even when I overclock it, it isn't capable of running the backend and the conversion at the same time.

Comment: A raspberry pi has WAY more than enough processing power to mux an annexb stream into an mp4 container. All it needs to do is write the moov atom, convert start codes to lengths, and write the stream to the mdat. Any CPU ever made could do it without 'crashing'. It just may do it slowly.

Comment: That is true, but my raspberry pi is also running my own software project which is what creates these videos and runs the webserver. So combining all that, and it is not able to do the conversion

Comment: Ill take your word for it, but I still think you are over estimating the overhead of re-muxing. The video does not need to be re-encoded. transmuxing is only slightly more work than a file copy.